# Get networkx graph from xml file (xmlns)

Tags: python-3.x, xml, networkx, xml-namespaces

**I want a networkx graph from a xml file (xmlns).**

I understand that the namespaces are the issue, but reading several questions, trying out different parsers and answers aren’t getting me there. (Engineer wanting to solve stuff by googling, not a capable coder)

**XML content**

Here follows modified xml file content.

*Note*
Many instances of the same type are removed, but all unique type of instances are present. Ie. it won’t make sense to parse this data, as too much is missing/ altered to give any relationships.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PrE xmlns:dat="Example-Z 098-dat-11#">    
    <Segment>
        <mRID>021b10cc-bbd1-6789-9aac-4606dec13bac</mRID>
        <Type ref="f84b0acc-6789-5ccc-bf88-01bad39b3c5b"/>
        <BaVe ref="8c07516d-6789-59d2-b72f-ebc73fc4d06f"/>
        <le multiplier="none" unit="m">64.536756123411005</le>
        <r7bv multiplier="none" unit="R"></r7bv>
        <gbv multiplier="none" unit="L"></gbv>
        <a multiplier="none" unit="red">0.034</a>
        <a0 multiplier="none" unit="red">0.034</a0>
        <b multiplier="none" unit="red">0.008987762298886673</b>
        <b0 multiplier="none" unit="red">1.1234702988684403E-05</b0>
    </Segment>
    <BaVe>
        <mRID>8c07516d-6789-59d2-b72f-ebc73fc4d06f</mRID>
        <nomVa multiplier="none" unit="V">230</nomVa>
    </BaVe>
    <BaVe>
        <mRID>fe55884e-6789-57f6-b284-2601144b69cc</mRID>
        <nomVa multiplier="none" unit="W">3</nomVa>
    </BaVe>
    <BSect>
        <mRID>0d4e1b71-6789-517e-852f-f444c8a4a85c</mRID>
        <name>RG123456-BSect</name>
    </BSect>
    <BSect>
        <mRID>d1378e42-445f-5db1-b777-4de56d7a9c8b</mRID>
        <name>NV9498 - t 1-BSect</name>
    </BSect>
    <ConN>
        <mRID>2988efc1-76b1-6789-98d6-12f9bded6863</mRID>
    </ConN>
    <EC>
        <mRID>034ecb27-9689-6789-9de2-70bcf52e69d2</mRID>
        <BaVe ref="8c07516d-2004-59d2-b72f-ebc73fc4d06f"/>
    </EC>
    <ExtNIExt>
        <mRID>4303272d-ae0b-5b2b-bb24-6789c6b9b658</mRID>
        <maxA multiplier="none" unit="A">1871.59</maxA>
        <minA multiplier="none" unit="A">1239.93</minA>
        <vF>1</vF>
        <cP>0.11</cP>
        <BaVe ref="fe55884e-7669-57f6-b284-2601144b69cc"/>
    </ExtNIExt>
    <PT>
        <mRID>e16f22ef-6789-5c9b-a6df-63fe2b21c56a</mRID>
        <name>1002988</name>
        <ECont ref="a1ac4bd1-be54-5e65-9de4-4d2988d3b796"/>
    </PT>
    <PTEE>
        <mRID>12ef14df-4c9c-5c30-ab39-6789ff57f71a</mRID>
        <eMo>2</eMo>
        <rA multiplier="none" unit="G">123</rA>
        <rS multiplier="none" unit="GA">100</rS>
        <r0>0</r0>
        <x0>0</x0>
        <Lk>3.2988999713897696</Lk>
        <Lr>1.2988999999999999</Lr>
        <PT ref="e16f22ef-1593-5c9b-a6df-63fe2b21c56a"/>
        <Term ref="a5142186-d1e6-5940-b161-92ee5d6e5fd5"/>
        <BaVe ref="8c07516d-2004-59d2-b72f-ebc73fc4d06f"/>
    </PTEE>
    <Type>
        <mRID>8e8072d6-599d-593e-6789-e4c432cf2c4d</mRID>
        <name>Cap</name>
    </Type>
    <Type>
        <mRID>b59fefe6-3eda-6789-958f-4678140c6db8</mRID>
        <name>SecS</name>
    </Type>
    <Type>
        <mRID>c31ef7d7-9d5f-5e09-9e1f-5d5d8406c0b8</mRID>
        <name>Unk</name>
    </Type>
    <Type>
        <mRID>f84b0acc-6357-5ccc-bf99-01bad39b3c5b</mRID>
        <name>OLi</name>
    </Type>
    <RTC>
        <mRID>92bea3ad-5ec7-562b-b7e8-3a54f825558d</mRID>
        <stepVI>2.5</stepVI>
        <TEd ref="12ef14df-4c9c-5c30-ab39-7423ff57f71a"/>
    </RTC>
    <Sub>
        <mRID>a1ac4bd1-be54-5e65-9de4-4d6789d3b796</mRID>
        <name>NL1234</name>
        <description>Rid 42</description>
        <Type ref="b59fefe6-3eda-5465-958f-4678140c6db8"/>
    </Sub>
    <Term>
        <mRID>0036a224-cdbe-6789-955b-f662ea2432d8</mRID>
        <seqNo>2</seqNo>
        <ConN ref="cfb319a5-e9be-5d31-ac31-5186e9fa5b26"/>
        <CondE ref="70fc91e6-9ce4-5e42-a813-8c39407a3c92"/>
    </Term>
    <UPExt>
        <mRID>0b8e056c-1eab-9d4c-a6f2-e2d3bc56ae56</mRID>
        <measID>678967896789678995</measID>
        <Eq ref="cc3d36bb-9329-6789-b8d2-53c0b99f9504"/>
    </UPExt>
    <LBS>
        <mRID>2d9deef5-603e-5387-8d06-8744a75b6aa6</mRID>
        <name>1</name>
        <noO>false</noO>
    </LBS>
    <Brak>
        <mRID>8903a50b-c841-6789-bb6d-066198cece5d</mRID>
        <name>CV98743.1</name>
        <noO>false</noO>
    </Brak>
    <Funv>
        <mRID>ad7dd46d-3c81-6789-aac3-cb01f083a897</mRID>
        <name>3</name>
        <noO>false</noO>
    </Funv>
</PrE>
```

Comment: There is a `xmlns:dat="Example-Z 098-dat-11#"` namespace declaration, but that namespace is not actually used in the XML file. So it cannot be the case that "the namespaces are the issue".

Comment: How can I set up something to parse or convert this in some way that makes me capable of creating a networkx graph? I assumed namespaces was the issue after much failing and a lot of googling, getting me onto the xmlns track.  Can I convert xml to something better? Thankfull for any tip getting me closer to my goal.

Comment: I think you should start by learning some basics about extracting data from an XML document. For example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial.

Comment: I have tried many things, and neither ElementTree nor BeautifulSoup is able to parse my file ‘of the shelf’. It’s probably due to my lack of knowledge, but I have tried. I am able to read all the children and pick out parts of information as I want,by combining BeautifulSoup and ElementTree. But I don’t understand how to structure and feed this data so the result is a networkx graph. And, when working with many ‘manual’ steps to get the data out the file, I’m thinking there must be a better way for this. That is what I am seeking. Can you provide any tips, @mzjn?

Comment: I know quite a bit about XML in general, but nothing about NetworkX. What kind of information is in your XML file? It looks rather opaque to me.

Comment: It is a type of circuit, much is missing here, but all unique children are present. For every child, many many more of the same instances but with unique mRIDs. In the original file, everything is connected.